# Angularjs: ngResource can't get the response from SpringData's returns

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

js file:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);


app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

    return $resource("/apis/getPageData.req/:id")

}]);


app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "baseRequest", function ($scope, baseRequest) {

    var self = this;

    self.users = [];


    self.fetchAllUsers = function () {

        self.users = baseRequest.query();

        console.log(self.users);
    };

    self.fetchAllUsers();

}]);
```

SpringMVC controller file:

```
@RequestMapping("/apis")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPageData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<User> getDatas(@RequestParam(value = "pageNo",required = false,defaultValue = "1"
    ) String No) {

        int pageNo = Integer.parseInt(No);

        if (pageNo < 0) {

            pageNo = 1;
        }

        return userDao.getPageData(pageNo);
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAll() {

        return userDao.getAll();

    }
}
```

When I request for the method getAll(), everything goes well. But when I request for the getDatas(), It goes wrong, ngResource can't get the response, it shows me the error as following:

This error occurs when the $resource service expects a response that can be deserialized as an array but receives an object, or vice versa. By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.

To resolve this error, make sure your $resource configuration matches the actual format of the data returned from the server.

[error info in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRtNU.png)

I don't know how to match the actual format of the data returned from the server.

Actually, I need all the information of Object Page, include the array of User.

Page includes pageNo, currentPage,totallSize,User and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I just made a mistake for that. That's so easy.

```
   app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

    return $resource("/apis/getPageData.req/:id", {id: '@id'}, {

        query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}
    });

}]);
```